# code throws NullReferenceException when add an item to dictionary inside factory startnew

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, dictionary

I have C# code; when run to a line, it throws a `System.NullReferenceException`.

Here is the line of the code that cause the exception

```
if (expDic != null && expression != null)
{
    expDic.Add(i, expression.ToString())
}
```

Here is the stack trace in the code

```
 at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Sustainability.BusinessObject.CalculationManager.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<HandleFormulaInner>b__0(Object args) in D:\HK\Desktop\VSTS_2\Sustainability.BusinessObject\Classes\CalculationManager.cs:line 1410
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I found that both `expDic` and `expression` are not null, however it throws a null reference exception.

Here is my code:

```
            int count = table.Rows.Count;
            Dictionary<int, string> expDic = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

            for (int f = 0; f < count; f++)
            {
                DataRow tempformula = table.Rows[f];
                string formulaSymbol = Convert.ToString(tempformula[Common.Systems.Sustainability.Constants.IndicatorFormula.Symbol]);

                  var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action<object>((args) => {
                    int i = (int)args;

                    _sem.Wait();
                    StringBuilder expression = new StringBuilder(1024);

                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            // symbol in the last line of formula
                            if (exp.EndsWith("+")
                                || exp.EndsWith("-")
                                || exp.EndsWith("*")
                                || exp.EndsWith("/"))
                            {
                                exp = exp.Substring(0, exp.Length - 1);
                            }
                            object result = dt.Compute(exp, "");
                            expression.Append(result);
                        }
                    }

                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(symbol)
                            && expression.Length > 0)
                        {
                            if (i + 1 >= count && symbol != ")")
                            {
                            }
                            else if (expression.ToString() != symbol)
                            {
                                expression.Append(symbol);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (expression.Length == 0 && symbol == "(")
                        {
                            expression.Append(symbol);
                        }

                        if (symbol == "days")
                        {
                            // calculating average values by days.
                            if (fromDate != null && toDate != null)
                            {
                                int days = toDate.Value.Subtract(fromDate.Value).Days + 1;
                                expression.Append(days);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                expression.Append(1);
                            }
                        }
                    } 

                    //Here is the code will have problem
                    if (expDic != null && expression != null)
                    {
                        expDic.Add(i, expression.ToString());
                    }

                    _sem.Release();
                }), f);

                taskList.Add(t);
            }
```

I am doubting it is caused by the `StartNew` multithreading pattern,
so what is wrong in my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please post the actual stack trace in its entirety.

Comment: Have you declare the expDic and Expression?

Comment: @Syafiqur__. Yes expDic and Express are declared

Comment: What statement that select the data? Is this `DataSet indicator = GetIndicatorByIDFromCache(companyID, indID);`

Comment: @Syafiqur__ Yes. ```DataSet indicator = GetIndicatorByIDFromCache(companyID, indID)``` select the data

Comment: Try add `SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: @Syafiqur__ Where should I add ```SingleOrDefault```

Comment: Like this `DataSet indicator = GetIndicatorByIDFromCache(companyID, indID).SingelOrDefault();`

Comment: @Syafiqur__ Why SingleOrDefault can solve the problem?

Comment: it returns a default value of a specified generic type, instead of throwing an exception if no element found for the specified condition. However, it will thrown InvalidOperationException if it found more than one element for the specified condition in the collection.

Comment: @JohnWu stack trace has been added.

Comment: @Syafiqur__ I use ```DataSet indicator = indicatorMgr.GetIndicatorByID(companyID, indID);```. But I cannot find and add SingleOrDefault for it.

Comment: `DataSet indicator = new indicatorMgr.GetIndicatorByID(companyID, indID).SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: What is the value of _f_ you are marshalling through? You have duplicate keys in the dict.

Comment: @dfhwze code added. the f marshal through will be the records of table.